# Using css href online is OK, then download css file and use it locally it is not working at all

Tags: html, css

So I am working on personal website project. And I am using html template of w3school. They use css file from online source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
awesome.min.css">
```

Everthing works fine until I download all the css file locally and load them from local position like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="./assets/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="./assets/google_raleway.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="./assets/font_awesome.min.css">
```

The form of website is totally wrecked after I use local css file instead of online source. I inspect the page and in console, there is no error message on css part. I don't know why it is not working locally.

Comment: Where is your html in relation to the css? Is it on the same directory level as the assets?

Comment: Check the paths that you given

Comment: Also, change `type` to `text/css` instead...

Comment: @Kevin the path is correct. Like I said I inspect the console. There is no error.

Comment: @Studocwho If I change `type` to `text/css`, It would raise error in console: `Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/font_awesome.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: So then the first thing you have to do, is figure out how to get your system to deliver such CSS resources with the proper Content-Type. `type="text/html"` was just completely bogus to begin with, that makes zero sense.

Comment: There is obviously something wrong with your setup on your machine, because the correct css type is as I've stated above: `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

Just Download all css in one folder.
And get full path of that files.

Example:
You Downloaded Files in below location **(i am using D drive(asset folder in D drive)** as an example here) of your computer:

```
D:\assets\w3.css
D:\assets\google_raleway.css
D:\assets\font_awesome.min.css

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\assets\w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\assets\google_raleway.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\assets\font_awesome.min.css">
```

If this works in full path means there is an error in you relative path you given.
So just do small research to set relative path.